# Is there a way to avoid checking dependencies with Composer?

Tags: composer-php

I'm running `php composer update mypackage` and it still checks other packages and downloads a bunch of files from packigist, taking a long time. Is there a way to just update 'mypackage' without doing any check to packagist.org?

Comment: This doesn't look possible to me as Composer will still need to check whether all constraints by the updated package will be fulfilled.

Comment: @xabbuh Any good practice to update our own dependencies using git and at the same time avoid checking all constraints?

Comment: Not that I'm aware. Why would you actually want to do that?

Comment: Basically, we are using `composer update` to get the latest version of our internal modules. Is there a better way of referencing them?